# strange haskell parse error

Tags: haskell, parse-error

So I've only a little experience with Haskell and I've been working on the below program to implement a search to find maxima in a function, yet I've been receiving an odd error. When I compile it says:

MaximaSearch.hs:26:1:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)

That's the line that says "main = do" so I think it's some sort of trailing error from my indentation in the code preceding it but I can't spot any mistakes...

Here's the code:

```
 module Main where                                                                  
  g :: Float -> Float                                                                
  --your function here                                                               
  g x = cos(x^2)                                                                     

  --goldenSectionSearch                                                              
  goldenSS :: (Float -> Float) -> Float -> Float -> Float -> Float -> Float          
  goldenSS f a b c tau                                                               
    | (c-a) < tau * (abs b + abs x) = (c+a)/2                                        
    |f x > f b = let                                                                 
                  t1|(c - b) > (b-a) = goldenSS f b x c tau                          
                    |otherwise = goldenSS f a x b tau                                
                  in t1                                                              
    |otherwise = let                                                                 
                  t2|(c-b) > (b-a) = goldenSS f a b x tau                            
                    |otherwise = goldenSS f x b c tau                                
                  in t2                                                              
    where                                                                            
      let x                                                                          
            | (c-b) >  (b-a) = b + resphi*(c-b)                                      
            |otherwise = b - resphi*(b-a)                                            
            where resphi = 2 - phi where phi = (1+ sqrt 5)/2                         
        in x                                                                         

  --main                                                                             
  main = do                                                                          
          print x                                                                    
          print (g x)                                                                
            where                                                                    
              x = goldenSS g a ((a+b)/2) b tau                                       
                where                                                                
                  a = 2                                                              
                  b = 3                                                              
                  tau = 0.001
```

any ideas?

Comment: Please get rid of the line numbers in your code sample.

Comment: ok, removed the numbers

Comment: There are many problems with your code... In particular, your use of guards inside a `let` binding is quite weird. Why not simply use an `if`-`then`-`else` expression instead?

Comment: well i'm new to haskell, but my intention was to implement something like:
if(condition 1){ 
    if(condition 2)
        return value 1
    else
        return value 2}

I had hoped to do this using nested guards until I realized haskell doesn't support them, so I hoped to simulate nested guards with the outer guard returning x and x dictated by the inner guards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting the parse error stems from the non-idiomatic usage of `let` and `where` bindings in your code.

Haskell allows multiple syntactic structures for temporary bindings and pattern matching, but you're combining them in a rather strange and messy manner.

To learn how to write the code cleaner and in a manner more usual for Haskell, I'd recommend looking up existing haskell libraries and programs (for example on [hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/)) to get a feel for how `let` and `where` bindings usually work. In general I find that for pure functions I almost exclusively use `where` (as opposed to `let`), but certain things are stylistic.

As for this code, I modified it a bit to use `where` bindings instead of `let`, and it compiles and runs for me now. Even if you have to tweak it a bit to get it to compile for you, this overall structure is cleaner and less likely to give you parse errors:

```
module Main where                                 

g :: Float -> Float                                                      
g x = cos(x^2)                                                           

goldenSS :: (Float -> Float) -> Float -> Float -> Float -> Float -> Float 
goldenSS f a b c tau                                        
  |(c-a) < tau * (abs b + abs x) = (c+a)/2                               
  |f x > f b = t1                         
  |otherwise = t2                                      

  where x | (c-b) >  (b-a) = b + resphi*(c-b)                  
          |otherwise = b - resphi*(b-a)    

        resphi = 2 - phi

        phi = (1+ sqrt 5)/2                         

        t1 |(c - b) > (b-a) = goldenSS f b x c tau                         
           |otherwise = goldenSS f a x b tau       


        t2 |(c-b) > (b-a) = goldenSS f a b x tau                            
           |otherwise = goldenSS f x b c tau  



main =
  do                                                                          
    print x                                                                    
    print (g x)                                                                
  where x = goldenSS g a ((a+b)/2) b tau                                       
        a = 2                                                              
        b = 3                                                              
        tau = 0.001
```

Comment: No problem. I'm not the expert in Haskell, but I think the most important thing with indentation is that things line up, as opposed to them being at a certain depth.

For instance if you indent the `a = 2` line by 2 spaces, you'll get a parse error. But if you indent the `where` block 2 spaces and the definitions of `x`,`a`,`b, and `tau` 2 spaces as well so it all lines up, it'll compile fine. Again, just look at some existing Haskell projects, and you'll get a feel for it.

Comment: Also, make sure to always indent with spaces as opposed to tabs (or change your editor so it uses spaces for tab), they work better.